# CAstle Windsor: How to reference a second xml config file that is an embedded resource?

Tags: castle-windsor

We have one xml configuration file that we use in production. We also have a little test app that has a couple of additional needs. What I'd like to do is create a second, testing-only xml config file that references the embedded production configuration file. Is there any way to do this?

I'm aware of the "include" element, but am not sure where in the file it is supposed to be placed--in the castle node? The components node?

I feel like the answer is [here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=XML-Registration-Reference&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) but I'm too dense to figure it out.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

**UPDATE**

This is how our production config file is set up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OurCompany>
 <Framework>
  <castle>
   <installers>
     <!-- some installers-->
   <installers>
   <components>
       <!--some components-->
   <components>
  <castle>
 <Framework>
<OurCompany>
```

My most recent attempt at a non-production config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OurCompany>
 <Framework>
  <castle>
   <include uri="assembly://AssemblyContainingEmbeddedXml/MyEmbeddedConfig.xml" /> 
   <components>
       <!--components I only want registered with container when running in non-production environment-->
   <components>
  <castle>
 <Framework>
<OurCompany>
```

The exception I get reads:

Configuration parser encountered Framework, but it was expecting to find installers, facilities or components. There might be either a typo on  or you might have forgotten to nest it properly.

(In the actual message, "Framework," "installers," "facilities," and "components" are enclosed in angle brackets.)

Answer (score 4):

The bottom of the page you reference has an example of loading from an embedded resourced:

```
IResource resource = new AssemblyResource("assembly://Acme.Crm.Data/Configuration/services.xml");
container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(resource));
```

Comment: Thanks--can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Finally got back to this one. Even though I marked it as answer a while ago, I recently realized it didn't actually answer my issue. I'd like to reference the embedded xml config file from a different, non-production xml configuration file. from the documentation, I should in my NonProductionConfig.xml use something like <include uri="assembly://myDllName/ProductionConfig.xml" />. Is that correct? I can't get it to work. It doesn't see any of the services I register in ProductionConfig.xml.